# sharepoint registration change notification

Tags: notifications, event-handling, sharepoint-2013, user-registration

I have a class registration set up in SharePoint 2013.  Users are emailed when they register for a class.  I want to create email notifications when the Start Date, Start Time or Location [fields] of the Session changes.  I only want to email the users that have registered for said Session (between 1 and 400 people).

I should be able to handle this with an Alert or an Event, but can't figure it out.  My SharePoint team is telling me that this is too difficult because "the columns are in Sessions [list] and not in Registrations [list view].

I've found a lot of information on general SharePoint alerts, but I can't find anything on sending notifications to a select group of users, based on another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create event receiver for the list and send email by `SPUtility.SendEmail` with dynamic users.

You could check sample code from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195443/unable-to-send-email-through-sputility-sendemail).

[Create event receiver in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/).